# How to rewrite URL and return `404` for original links?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, web, url-rewriting

I created my website with some files in `htdocs` folder, such as: `.htaccess`, `web.php` ... In past, I used an old URL structure for my website: `old.php?id=12`. Then, I have used a new one: `new/12`, by using this simple `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule "^new/([0-9]+)/?$" "/old.php?$1"
```

And now, I do not want any user can access my website with old URL structure. Could you show me: How to rewrite URL and return `404` for original links?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^new/(\d+)*$ ./old.php?id=$1
```

Comment: Cheers amigo! Glad to help :-)

Comment: But it is not going to do what is requested, no 404 and no blocking of old url

Answer (score 1):

The best solution, especially for SEO, is to make a redirect 301:

```
RewriteEngine on

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+old\.php\?id=(\d+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /new/%1? [R=301,L,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^new/(\d+)/?$ /old.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

To get a real 404 effortlessly, the simplest is to change your hidden page name to new.php (also in htaccess) and delete the old.php page.